# How to output unsigned char to a text file in c?

Tags: c

I've got an array of unsigned chars that I'd like to output to a file using the C file I/O. What's a good way to do that? Preferably for now, I'd like to output just one unsigned char.

My array of unsigned chars is also non-zero terminated, since the data is coming in binary.

Comment: There is a pretty limited number of ways to do that. What have you already evaluated?

Comment: For one char, use [`fputc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputc.html). For several chars, use `fputc()` in a loop.

Comment: And read up on [opening and writing to files in C](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output#example-write).

Comment: For more than one char use fwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use function `fwrite` to write binary data to a file; obviously the solution works for arrays of `SIZE==1` as well:

```
int main() {
#define SIZE 10

    unsigned char a[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    FILE *f1 = fopen("file.bin", "wb");
    if (f1) {
        size_t r1 = fwrite(a, sizeof a[0], SIZE, f1);
        printf("wrote %zu elements out of %d requested\n", r1,  SIZE);
        fclose(f1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have, as you claim, an *array* of input (not just a *pointer* to the first element of the array), you don't need a null terminator. The array will also have length information:

```
size_t len = sizeof myarray;
// To write a single char:
fputc(myarray[0], fp);
// To write the entire array:
fwrite(myarray, 1, len, fp);
```

If you do want to output the entire array

Answer (score 0):

> I've got an array of unsigned chars that I'd like to output
>   How to output unsigned char to a text file in c?

The tricky part is "to a **text** file".  This usually means to save something human readable.

If that is the goal, then save printable characters as text and non-printable ones as escaped text - also special handling of `'\n'` and `'\\'`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_1_uchar(FILE *stream, unsigned char uch) {
  if ((isprint(uch)) && ch != '\\') || ch == '\n') {
    fputc(uch,  stream);
  } else {
    fprintf(stream, "\\x03o", uch);
  }
}

void print_1_array(FILE *stream, const void *a, size_t sz) {
  const unsigned char *s = a;
  while (sz-- > 0) {
    print_1_uchar(stream, *s++);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
unsigned char foo[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
print_1_array(stdout, foo, sizeof foo);
```